# How to Enable Teamcity Performance Monitor

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I couldn't find any information related about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance monitor is a build feature. Build features can be added on build steps administration page, see button "Add Build Feature".